# Handling sockets in event loops

Tags: c++, sockets, event-handling

Can anyone recommend an elegant and efficient framework to craft a main event loop in C++ where I need to do the following:

- Handle keyboard input
- Check for incoming datagrams on a socket
- Queue and send outgoing reply datagrams
- Manage curses-based windowing

I'm familiar with Cocoa mostly, and all of that functionality is conveniently wrapped into the core classes. For portability, and to knock off some rust, I chose C++ to write this network-client app based on curses (for that sporty IRC/terminal look). Yes, I'm a glutton for punishment.

Would an observer pattern work? Perhaps setting up a global notification center to register for and receive messages? Should the network part run on it's own thread? The goal is to produce a version for unix, linux and windows at some point, so portability is the focus.

Any recommendations on classes for any of this would be helpful. I'm looking at ZMQ for handling the networking, but I'm not sure it'll handle UDP datagram service.

Comment: What's wrong with a good old "while()" loop with a ["select()" and a case block](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html)?

Comment: So do you need a networking library or a GUI library?

Comment: @H2CO3, apparently a library that is both

Comment: @paulsm4, the problem is that select blocks.  when select blocks and you're using the same loop for UI type stuff, your program becomes unusable.  I can't help but try to fill in OP's last name.

Comment: You will probably need to write a library on your own. Windows has ::WSAAsyncSelect which will use Windows Messages to communicate instead of blocking your main thread. Unfortunately I do not know how this would be handled on unix or linux.

Comment: If using several threads is a valid option, I'd do keyboard/GUI in one thread and use libevent in the other. Otherwise, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` may be a good candidate under Windows with no really good alternative (`poll` with timeout = 0 maybe?) under POSIX. Problem is, doing "network stuff" and "interactive gui" all at the same time is not something select-alike APIs are typically designed for. Using ZMQ "for networking" is probably also not a good idea, because "networking" is not really what it does. ZMQ sends messages, with some very peculiar rules/conditions/twists.

Comment: So I'm thinking that multiple threads has to be a given. Perhaps having a simple observer sitting in the main thread for the "networking" piece would at least give me a way to periodically give the network thread service time, and then just focus on the UI stuff in the main thread. Or, as Damon menioned, handle both in separate threads and have 2 listeners and then just loop through checking for waiting messages in the listeners and servicing system stuff on the main thread. Does that sound reasonable?